# Why is my main not finding the functions from my shared library?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I have 4 separate functions in 4 different files. The functions look like this:

SieveOfEratosthenes.cpp

```
bool SieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {
//
}
```

They all have no includes. In my main.cpp program I have

```
//Includes
void compare(bool (*f)(int)) {
//
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  compare(isPrimeAKS);
  compare(isPrimeModulo);
  compare(isPrimeSQRT);
  compare(SieveOfEratosthenes);
  return 0;
}
```

This is my makefile:

```
all: main clean

main: main.cpp lib.so
    g++ -o main main.cpp -L.

lib.so: EratosthenesSieve.o AKS.o ModuloAlg.o SQRTModuloAlg.o
    g++ -shared -o lib.so AKS.o ModuloAlg.o SQRTModuloAlg.o EratosthenesSieve.o

EratosthenesSieve.o: EratosthenesSieve.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall -fpic EratosthenesSieve.cpp

AKS.o: AKS.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall -fpic AKS.cpp

ModuloAlg.o: ModuloAlg.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall -fpic ModuloAlg.cpp

SQRTModuloAlg.o: ModuloAlg.cpp
    g++ -c -Wall -fpic SQRTModuloAlg.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Compiling errors at main(after building the shared library lib.so) with errors like:

> ‘isPrimeAKS’ was not declared in this scope.

I don't understand why, since they all are in the library provided to the compiler.

EDIT if you have the same problem: After declaring in a header the problem becomes

> undefined reference to `isPrimeAKS(int)'
>   see the accepted answer why.

Comment: Do you declare e.g. `isPrimeAKS`? You do not show any forward declarations or header files in your question.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: `g++ -o main main.cpp -L.` is missing the library. `lib.so` isn't the best name though. If you link with `x` (`-lx`) it will search for a file named `libx.so` or `libx.a`.

Comment: Oh man, I always forget the header. Now, after adding the header for the declarations, I have a novel problem, I get main.cpp:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to `isPrimeAKS(int)' which I think is because the compiler references to the uninitialized declaration instead of the function in the dynamic library. Editing

Comment: @UserX They are undefined because you haven't linked with your library.

Comment: Doesn't the . on the -L search the current directory for .so files?

Comment: Yes, but you don't supply any library to look for. Look at my first comment. You must supply a library with `-l` but the name you've chosen isn't the best. Say you named your library `libfoo.so`. You must then supply `-lfoo` when compiling.

Comment: Ohhh it ignores ^(lib).*(.so)$, I couldn't pick a worse name. That makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, the prototype of the function `isPrimeAKS` must be *declared* in the headers included in `main.cpp` or in the beginning of `main.cpp` (at least before it is called).

Secondly, you should link the dynamic library at compile time or load it at runtime.
Indeed, `g++ -o main main.cpp -L.` do not link `lib.so`. You need to add the `-lyourlib` option. However, since this option ignore the prefix `lib` and the suffix `.so`, you need to change the invalid name of `lib.so` to something valid like `libaks.so` and then link it with `g++ -o main main.cpp -L. -laks`.